# Can't post Norwegian characters through POST function

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a small issue about posting Norwegian characters with the `$_POST` function in PHP. It works very well when i'm manually insert the "ÆØÅ" like written below.

**See 'title'**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (w_id, author_u_id, ec_id, title, contents, draft, privacy, date, comments, random) 
VALUES ('$weblog_info[w_id]', '$user_info[u_id]', '$ec_id', 'ÆØÅ', '$contents', '$draft', '3', '$time', '$real_comments', '$random')")
```

However, when I'm using `$_POST` to submit 'title' with Norwegian characters it returns blank.

Any ideas?

**Edit: Using ISO-8859-1**

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Probably the webpage has different encoding than the script and database.

Comment: Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your HTML.

Comment: Nevertheless please don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extension.

Comment: could it be possible you need to use mb_convert_encoding or the alike?

Comment: @Akam don't mind the terrible structure and codes. Will fix that eventually. http://pastebin.com/uKHwnau6

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Why are you so sure he uses UTF-8?

Comment: of course first of all it is necessary to check if posted data are posted and received properly

Comment: You need to use the same encoding in the webpage and the database. You can set encoding of the db like @Ilya has shown; the same encoding must be on the webpage. Maybe your db is not ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @Voitcus There's no option for ISO-8859-1 as I can see. But i think default is latin1_danish_ci. Is this right?

Comment: @user2217702 I don't know, I always use UTF-8 and have no problems like that :) I think ISO-8859-1 is `latin-1`